# jquery autocmplete search json POST

Tags: jquery, json, joomla3.0

I have developed jquery autocomplete search on my joomla module. there i have and issue, if i type the file path where json codes was place and put `http://localhost/project/modules/mod_jtory_search/tmpl/personal.php?term=c` it will display results , this is not good for security , can any one advice how to fix this using POST method ?

json

```
    $db = JFactory::getDbo();
$searchp=$_GET["term"];
$searchp = str_replace(' ', '', $searchp);

$query = $db -> getQuery(true);


  $query="SELECT * FROM tent WHERE REPLACE(title, ' ', '') LIKE '%$searchp%' AND categories_id=82 order by title ASC ";

$db -> setQuery($query);
// Load the results as a list of associated arrays.
$results = $db -> loadAssocList();
$json=array();
foreach ($results as $json_result) {
    $json[] = array('value' => $json_result["title"], 'label' => $json_result["title"]);
}echo json_encode($json);
```

autocomplete

```
    jQuery.noConflict();
                 jQuery(function(){
                     jQuery("#searchp").autocomplete({
                         source:'<?php echo JURI::root().'modules/mod_jtory_search/tmpl/personal.php'; ?>',
                        delay: 300 ,
                         minLength:1
                     });
                jQuery(function () {
        jQuery("#searchp").keypress(function (e) {
            if (e.keyCode == 13) {
                return false;
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Information sent over GET or POST are both insecure and visible to anyone who knows where to look. Auto complete should not usually expose something sensitive. But you should think of securing your application by validation rather than obscuring.

In other words, consider using HTTPS or consider making it available only for users with certain permissions.

To use POST you can check the example [here](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote-jsonp) which shows you a simple way of using an AJAX call to get the data for the autocomplete. Then all you need to do is set the `type` option in the `ajax` call to `POST` as shown [here](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)